# TypeError: Object of type TypeError is not JSON serializable Python

Tags: python, json

So I have JSON request with format like this:

```
{
"item_ids": [635,10,692,194,9412],
"gender": "male",
"number_results": 5
}
```

I'm trying to parse array in "item_ids". But I got error message like in the title. This is my code:

```
resto_id = json.loads['item_ids']
data  = json.dumps(resto_id)
```

I also tried this:

```
response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8520/recommend_multi")
users = json.loads(response.text)
data = users['item_ids']
```

But gave me an error:

```
TypeError: Object of type JSONDecodeError is not JSON serializable
```

Edit: Maybe this will help:

```
@app.route('/recommend_multi', methods=['POST'])
def recommend_multi():

    dct={}
    new_user = 'newusername'
    try:
        e=""
        resto_id = json.loads['item_ids']
        data  = json.dumps(resto_id)
        # response = requests.get("http://127.0.0.1:8520/recommend_multi")
        # users = json.loads(response.text)
        # data = users['item_ids']
        
        gender = request.json['gender']
        resto_rec = float(request.json['number_results'])

        input_dict = {'id_resto': data,
        'gender': [gender, gender, gender, gender, gender], 'username': [new_user, new_user, new_user, new_user, new_user]}
        
        dct = {"items": input_dict}
        dct2 = {"data": dct, "message":"sukses", "success":True}

    except Exception as e:
        dct2 = {"data": dct, "message":e, "success":False}
    

    return jsonify(dct2)
```

And this is the traceback:
[image]
[image]
I run it with docker. And for request I'm using Insomnia

Comment: Can you share reproducible code that we can run? And also the full traceback if possible

Comment: You mean like a full code?

Comment: Not necessarily. Just code that resembles your real code, and we can run that gives the same error you are getting.

Comment: I do some edit. Sorry I post the traceback with images because it says too many codes in my post

Answer (score 3):

The problem is in this snippet:

```
    except Exception as e:
        dct2 = {"data": dct, "message":e, "success":False}
```

You are basically trying to JSON serialize the exception `e` which is not possible. You need to use something that is JSON serializable, like the string representation of the exception, for example by using `str(e)`:

```
    except Exception as e:
        dct2 = {"data": dct, "message":str(e), "success":False}
```

Comment: It works thanks. But then I got the exception message `'function' object is not subscriptable`

Comment: Can you edit your problem description and add traceback as well? But judging from the code, it should be because of `json.loads['item_ids']`. `loads` is a function, not something subscriptable like a dictionary

Comment: The code is running, no error message. It seems catch an error above so it gave me a response from `except` condition. This is the response `{
  "data": {},
  "message": "'function' object is not subscriptable",
  "success": false
}`

Comment: If you temporarily remove the try except, it should tell you which line is causing the problem

Comment: Yeah, but for handling json request format above, am I already right for getting array data in "item_ids"? Because I can't found example for getting array data in "item_ids" in my case and with json request format like above

Comment: How exactly do you receive `item_ids`? Is it from another API call?

Comment: With this `resto_id = json.loads['item_ids']`

Comment: `json.loads(somedata['item_ids'])`?

Comment: Sorry for not responding you. I finally got the solution. I can do that but only the JSON request format like this: `somedata = {
"item_ids": [635,10,692,194,9412],
"gender": "male",
"number_results": 5
}` if I'm not wrong.

Answer (score 0):

First, thanks to @bdbd to keep responding to me. The exception solution helped me to fix my code, but in the end I managed to debug my code then found the solution which is resolve my problems about retrieving array in JSON objects. So instead of this:

```
resto_id = json.loads['item_ids']
data  = json.dumps(resto_id)
```

I need to request first.

```
resto_id = request.json
data  = json.dumps(resto_id)
data2 = json.loads(data)
#Then retrieve the array
data2["item_ids"]
```

Comment: Actually you can just do `request.json()['item_ids']`. No need to dump it and then load it back.